# How to eliminate the repeated words in a list opened from a txt file?

Tags: list, python-3.x

[image: Code]

If I am getting a txt file with a paragraph, and I already translate the paragraph into a list. How should I eliminate the repeated words?

[image: Output]

Comment: provide what you have done so far

Comment: please never provide code as images.

Comment: If you get answers that are useful, you should upvote them and if one works for you, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about python, you can use `set()` to remove duplicate words from a list.

```
myList = ["word", "word", "test", "hey", "hello", "world", "hello"]
set(myList)
```

This returns

```
set(['test', 'world', 'word', 'hey', 'hello'])
```

If you want to allow for mixed lowercase and uppercase words you could also do something like

```
set([ word.lower() for word in myList ])
```

If you want all uppercase like the elements in the list in the photo you linked, just replace `.lower()` with `.upper()`